# Color in QGIS 3 points based on userid

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have a dataset in the from:

```
gps.accuracy    latitude    longitude   timestamp   user
37.959  -9.6580833  -35.7001122 1434057621378   5573502c150000c10136e51b
37.959  -9.6580833  -35.7001122 1434059660236   5573502c150000c10136e51b
37.959  -9.6580833  -35.7001122 1434060748144   5573502c150000c10136e51b
37.959  -9.6580833  -35.7001122 1434057621378   5573502c1000000000000000
37.959  -9.6580833  -35.7001122 1434059660236   5573502c1000000000000000
37.959  -9.6580833  -35.7001122 1434060748144   5573502c0000000000000000
```

There are two user (this is the id and several points for each one of them).

IN QGIS 3 I manage to add the points on map using the Data Source Management, Delimited Text. This is an example (of course above dataset is a sample):

[image]

I wonder if it is possible for every user, to have a different color in order to see the different points for the different user. Also is it possible to draw a line between points of the same user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah. [ahmadhanb](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/63384/ahmadhanb) has already answered the first one :)

Use **Points to path** tool for your second question:

[image]

[image]

Comment: In fact I forgot the other question. +1 from me.

Answer (score 3):

Save your data as shapefile and load the shapefile into QGIS canvas. Then right-click the shapefile `-> Properties -> Symbology -> Categorized -> From Column select User -> Classify`:

[image]

The points will be classified by User.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Also there is a way to connect these points with line?

Comment: @Antonis Yes you can look at Kazuhito's answer.